# nodejs handling callbacks in promisses

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, callback

I am tying out node.js, but not able to wrap my head around why one works and other doesn't

can you explain to me why
this works:

```
 app.delete('/notes/:id', (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const details = { '_id': new ObjectID(id) };
        db.collection('note')
        .deleteOne(details)
        .then((result) => res.send(result))
        .catch((err) => {
          !error.logged && logger.error('Mongo error', err);
          error.logged = true;
          throw err;
        });
      });
```

but this never enters the callback function and gets stuck in deleteOne, but in db we see entry is removed

```
app.delete('/notes/:id', (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const details = { '_id': new ObjectID(id) };
        db.collection('note').deleteOne(details, (err, item) => {
          if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
          } else {
            res.send('Note ' + id + ' deleted!');
          } 
        });
```

also all examples i see , they say below code should work but it never enters callback, it does make db connection i can see in db logs

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
console.log("hello");
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  var myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
  dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document inserted");
    db.close();
  });
}); 
console.log("bye");
```

what exactly i am missing here, or there is issue with my system?

this below a very simple example of callback from chatgpt works

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Function to read a file asynchronously and invoke a callback when done
function readFileAsync(filePath, callback) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(err, null); // Pass the error to the callback
    } else {
      callback(null, data); // Pass the data to the callback
    }
  });
}

// Example usage of the readFileAsync function
const filePath = 'example.txt';

readFileAsync(filePath, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error reading the file:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('File content:', data);
  }
});
```

why inbuilt callbacks not working?

Comment: I'm surprised that one works but not the other. I think the mongo functions, when sent a callback, will call the callback. With no callback, they return a promise.  The most pronounced difference between the two is that the first version sends the deleteOne result as the response; the second version sends a string.  My advice is to double check whether the callback is entered.

Comment: @danh do you mean put a debugger and see whether it is in that code block? if so i have tried that and it is not entering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Node.js and everything to do with the MongoDB driver.

See [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/upgrade/#version-5.x-breaking-changes).

> The driver removes support for callbacks in favor of a promise-based API.

The examples that you say you see, which show the callback approach working, are **old and out of date**. When a third-party tutorial doesn’t work, you should check against the official documentation.

Comment: yes found the same , thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour in the versions 5.x+ of the MongoDB API.

See [MongoDB docs: Upgrade Driver Versions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/upgrade/#std-label-node-breaking-changes-v5.x):

> #### Version 5.x Breaking Changes
>
> - The driver removes support for callbacks in favor of a promise-based API.

This change had been announced at the [release of version 4.10](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/whats-new/#what-s-new-in-4.10):

> #### Callback Deprecation
>
> Callbacks are now deprecated in favor of Promises. Callbacks will be removed in the next major release.

Comment: yes found the same , thanks :)

Comment: You can only mark one answer as accepted ,-)

Answer (score 0):

my  "mongodb": "^6.0.0" and mongodb has removed callback from 5.0.0 from this doc [mongo release doc](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-nodejs-driver-5-0-0-released/211452) ,concluding this is the reason why callbacks to db is not working. If anyone has other reasons please share